# Change Name of LLVM Function

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I have a LLVM Module object which contains a particular function that I would like to rename.  Is there any way of simply changing the name of a Function?

Comment: Can you at least include some code that demonstrates what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a module, you can look up a specific function by name using the [`getFunction` method](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a3f156c68d0efa530f05698ca15d66593), or you can iterate over all the functions in the module using `begin()` and `end()`. From there, `Function` inherits from `Value`, so you can just use the [`setName` method](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Value.html#a35ee267850af7c235474a8c46c7ac5af) change the name. This will also automatically update all the references and calls to it inside the same module.