# Rename a function in llvm

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I compiled a function into it's bitcode and I would like to change it's name which also means that all the functions that call it should call it's new name. I appreciate an advice to do so. Thanks

Comment: Did you create all the functions that call the function you are renaming?

Comment: I am working on the cpp file that was translated to bitcode  using  -emit-llvm . the file contains the function that I want to rename and the functions that calls it.

Comment: If you want to change the *.ll you can do so probably with a search and replace. Otherwise update the cpp and regenerate the bitcode.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking to do so in the bitcode level, Anyway, just found an answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990032/change-name-of-llvm-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Name of LLVM Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990032/change-name-of-llvm-function)