# LLVM - Rename Function inside a Module

Tags: clang, xcode7, llvm

I'm using llvm3.8 to make a `ModulePass` that, given a function name, it iterates through all the Modules's functions and searches for that name. 
Once the Function is found, it renames it with a String chosen randomly.

I need to run this pass on a iOS xcodeproject, so I am executing the pass by writing in the `OTHER_C_FLAGS`, in the project's build settings the command:

`-Xclang -load -Xclang path/to/my/ModulePass/RenameFunction.dlyb -mllvm -funcName="functionName"`

First thing I cannot figure out is the Extension Point that I should use in order to correctly rename the function:

`static RegisterStandardPasses RegisterClangPass(PassManagerBuilder::EP_EarlyAsPossible, registerClangPass);`

I tried with the `EP_EarlyAsPossible`, `EP_ModuleOptimizerEarly` and `EP_EnabledOnOptLevel0` but don't really know which one should be used in this case.

In order to rename the function I tried 2 different approaches, after finding the function:

1. By following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990032/change-name-of-llvm-function): Simply calling the Function's `setName()` method, setting it to the string I wanted.

`for (Module::iterator F = tmp->begin(), E = tmp->end(); F != E; F++) {
    Function *_F(F);
    if(checkName(_F->getName())){
        _F->setName(newNameString);
    }
}`

This doesn't compile for `EP_ModuleOptimizerEarly`. It compiles and runs for `EP_EarlyAsPossible` and `EP_EnabledOnOptLevel0`, but, by reverse engineering the app's binary, I noticed that the name didn't really change...

2. I tried cloning the original function, renaming it, changing all the original function's usages with the new clone and erasing the original one.

   `Function *clone = CloneFunction(_F, vMap, true);
   clone->setLinkage(GlobalValue::InternalLinkage);
   _F->getParent()->getFunctionList().push_back(clone);
   clone->setName(func_name);
   _F->replaceAllUsesWith(clone);
   _F->eraseFromParent();`

This is failing with clang error: `Running pass 'replaces function with a clone with a different name' on function.`

Comment: `EP_EarlyAsPossible` is for function passes, I'm pretty sure. It'll compile with a module pass but will do weird things. You probably want to register it for both `EP_ModuleOptimizerEarly` and `EP_EnabledOnOptLevel0`. When you say it doesn't compile for `EP_ModuleOptimizerEarly`, please show the error.

Comment: Just doing what you suggested with the registration for both `EP_ModuleOptimizerEarly` and `EP_EnabledOnOptLevel0` worked fine with the `setName()` solution. If you add a comment on the post I will be mothe than glad to mark it as answer!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is the correct one. Any issues you run into are likely because of how your pass is registered.

`EP_EarlyAsPossible` is for function passes. It'll compile with a module pass but will do weird things.

If your want your module pass to always run, you should register it for both `EP_EnabledOnOptLevel0` and `EP_ModuleOptimizerEarly`.

Comment: What kind of "weird things" to you expect? I think it should just work.

Comment: @Joky I remember trying it once and getting a weird segfault while iterating over the functions in the module and spending a day trying to track it down. If you look at the code in `PassManagerBuilder.cpp`, the `EP_EarlyAsPossible` passes are added only to `FPM`, the function pass manager. You can add any `Pass*`, but somewhere along the way it gets `static_cast` to a `FunctionPass*`, and this is UB if it's not actually a `FunctionPass*`. At least that's what I got out of it back then -- it was a little too template-heavy for my C++ skills to fully grasp.